# study the continuity of the function $f(x,y)$

Tags: analysis

[image]

is easy proof that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}{f(x,y)=0}$  however what is the value of $f(x,y)$ in $(0,0)$?

Comment: Please fix the typography of your post.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $f(x,0) = 0, \forall x\implies f(0,0) = 0$ also.